# How to make cascading HTTP requests with Flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, http, dart, request

I try to access my company **webservice** using a flutter app,

I have to first make a POST request where I send a **username** and a **password** (in a text/plain body),

Then I receive a **token** in the response,

Then I need to put this **token** in the URL of the next request to then again receive another **token**,

I am right now able to recuperate the first token but I have no clue how to put all these requests together,

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make use `async` `await`

```
void myFunction() async {
    final response = await http.post(_firstUri, body: _firstData);
    
    if(response.statusCode == 200)
        final String token = json.decode(response.body)['auth_token'];
 
    final anotherResponse = await http.post(_secondUri, body: {'data':token });
}
```

This way, the first API will be called first and the program won't move forward until the future gets completed.
I recommend putting everything inside try-catch block.